# Possible values of X-AppEngine-City header inserted by Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-headers

I am trying to display city specific phone numbers based on Appengine X-AppEngine-City. if user is from an city where we have an store display store phone number based on X-AppEngine-City information.

I can get X-AppEngine-City but cant any information on what google will respond for each city,

How to get list of all city names which X-AppEngine-City will respond with ??